# Should I use preposition or not

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

"He held the post () ten years."

I saw this line somewhere.It was written there that ten years is acting as adverb.But it seems stilted to me.I think **for** must be used in place of bracket.

Am I right,if not why?How to judge whether preposition should be placed or not?Or,is it okay with and without preposition both?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: @RonaldSole ?  You absolutely don't need *for* there.  Phrasings like "he lived ten years" are perfectly common: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lived+ten+years%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRrtPB_8_YAhUGq1MKHXuPC-AQpwUIHw&biw=1187&bih=859&dpr=1

Answer (score 1):

Both the following are acceptable and would be understood by native speakers to mean the same thing.

He held the post ten years.

He held the position **for** ten years.

The use of **for** in the second sentence is used to indicate a length of time.

Other examples:

He has been here **for** six hours.  **OR** He has been here six hours.

He was here **for** ten years.      **OR**  He  was here ten years.

However, some  **time** expressions which indicate duration need to have the preposition **for.**

e.g. He came to  live in this town **for** good. **= OK**

e.g.  He came to live in this town good.  **= WRONG.**